# grub menu vanish with login to ubuntu and just run ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grub-efi

I installed ubuntu 22.04 yesterday but face with a problem. I have ubuntu boot in bios options and windows boot and one another on HDD that while I installed ubuntu choose that HDD as boot option.

when I choose HDD in bios for boot I have grub menu and I can log into windows 10  but if I log choose ubuntu and log into it if I restart or shut down the system grub menu vanish and I directly log into ubuntu and when I check the bios the boot is on ubuntu not HDD.
could any one help me with this?

*********ps: even i lock the boot order on hdd  and now it's on it.it jut login to the ubuntu on the splash screen i need to reset the laptop use(ctrl+alt+del) to run the system again and now the grub appear. it's drive me crazy

Comment: Set that HDD as default boot option in the BIOS: then, grub will always be displayed. Otherwise, reinstall grub but this time on the drive that you boot by default.

Comment: @vanadium I try it but every time after i boot into Ubuntu i need to reset my laptop on splash screen to see grub.could my problem solve with change my boot loader software?

Comment: Then try reinstalling grub on the correct drive this time.

Comment: @vanadium sure i will do it.thanks